# If $X$ is a random variable, how can we show that $P(X<x) = P(\log X < \log x)$?

Tags: probability

If $X$ is a random variable, then often times we can find the transformation of a random variable through manipulating it's CDF. For example, if $X$ is a $\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ random variable, we have that

$-\log X \sim \operatorname{Expo}(1)$ by doing:

$$
P(-\log X < x) = P(\log X \geq -x) = P(X \geq e^{-x}) = e^{-x}
$$
which is the CDF of an exponential random variable. My question is:

1) What allows us to take monotonic transformations of both sides inside the probability operator? (i.e., in the first equality we multiplied $-1$ to both sides and in the second we took the exponential of both sides)

2) Does it matter whether we have strict inequalities on the inside?

Thanks!

Comment: It's fairly clear. $X \in (0, x) \Longleftrightarrow \log X \in (-\infty, \log x)$

Comment: I am not sure why what you wrote implies the two are equal under the probabilities. I understand that formally for the above expression to be equal, we must have: $\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) < x\} = \{\omega \in \Omega: \log(X(\omega)) < \log(x)\}$ almost surely. Is there a way to see this with what you wrote? Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)#Applying_a_function_to_both_sides As the comment from above, this fact is come from the property of inequalities when you apply a strictly increasing function on both sides of inequality. As it holds for real numbers, it also holds for real-valued random variable. When you have a "if and only if" relationship about two statements, the two corresponding sets characterized by them are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One finds probabilities of **events.** The two **events**, $X<x$ and $\log X < \log x,$ are in fact the same event, so they have the same probability.

Suppose, for example, that the probability space is the outcome of the toss of two coins. Let $1$ and $0$ correspond to heads and tails respectively. Then the space is
$$
\{(0,0),\  (1,0),\  (0,1),\  (1,1) \}.
$$
Now suppose $X$ is $1$ plus the number of heads that appear. Then we have
$$
X = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{with probability } 1/4, \\ 2 & \text{with probability }1/2, \\ 3 & \text{with probability }1/4. \end{cases}
$$
Since $2<e<3$ we have $\log 1 = 0 < 1< \log 2 < 1<\log 3,$ so the event $X<3$ is the set $\{(0,0),\ (1,0),\  (0,1)\}$ and the set $\log X < \log 3$ is also the set $\{(0,0),\ (1,0),\ (0,1)\}.$